# django migration impossible because of bug in field default value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am facing a strange situation with one of my django models.
I am using Django 1.10.3 with python 3.5.2.

The model looks like this (simplified for clarity):

```
class Report(models.Model):
    date = models.FieldDate()
    def fieldA_default(self):
        return MyObject.objects.filter(date=self.date).count()
    fieldA = models.IntegerField(default=fieldA_default)
```

I have the initial migration that creates the model and adds the field, autogenerated by django using `./manage.py makemigrations`.

I committed this code to my git repo, and deployed it to my production server, but the model isn't actually used (there are no `Report` objects in my database).
I just discovered that this code is incorrect ([django set default value of a model field to a self attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110654/django-set-default-value-of-a-model-field-to-a-self-attribute)) and decided to override `save()` instead.

But when I change the default from `fieldA_default` to `0`, running `./manage.py makemigrations` fails because it tries to run the old default value function `fieldA_default`. After trying a few options, I eventually decided to delete the model entirely. But that doesn't work either because `makemigrations` is still trying to run that same function.

Here is the traceback from `makemigrations` when I simply delete the model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 95, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 197, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 108, in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "xxx/reporting/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "xxx/reporting/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 22, in Migration
    ('fieldA', models.IntegerField(default=reporting.models.Report.fieldA_default)),
AttributeError: module 'reporting.models' has no attribute 'Report'
```

I have a few questions:

- why is Django running this "old" code even if I'm deleting the model?
- how did I manage to get this invalid code into a migration without Django screaming at me?
- how can I fix the situation so that I don't break my production server? I have no problem dropping the model entirely and rebuilding it, but I don't seem to be allowed to do it.

Comment: Have you tried migrating the app to zero, deleting the migration, and running `makemigrations` again?

Comment: I need info for a debug, please go into your db table django_migrations and check if row of "0001_initial" for your app exists. Add this to your post.

Comment: @schwobaseggl it looks like your suggestion worked. I ran `./manage.py migrate reporting zero` followed by `./manage.py makemigrations reporting` and I got no errors. Thanks for your help! If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: though I'm still wondering about the first 2 parts of my question...

Comment: @LaurentS Added an answer. Included some speculation wrt your other questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is Django running this "old" code even if I'm deleting the model?

Because the model and its method are still referenced in the migration file `0001_initial.py`

> But when I change the default from fieldA_default to 0, running ./manage.py makemigrations fails because it tries to run the old default value function fieldA_default.

I assume, after you reset the default value on the field, you removed the - now obsolete - method `fieldA_default`. As mentioned above this method is referenced in the initial migration which is now bound to break.

> how did I manage to get this invalid code into a migration without Django screaming at me?

When the migration was created, the code wasn't invalid. Some changes on the model cannot be handled by a simple forward migration. In your case:

- Deleting the model when it is referenced and imported in a migration file (which in itself is just another python module that cannot just import non-existing classes)
- same for removing the default method.

One thing you can do when your model code is messed up or out of sync with your migrations/db and `makemigrations` does not work from the current state, is the following:

1. `python manage.py migrate app_name zero  # undo all existing migrations of app`
2. Delete all migration files from the app. Optionally, if you already have valuable data in the db, you can undo them one-by-one and see if  step 3. already works
3. `python manage.py makemigrations app_name  # new start from clean sheet`

This is easy during development and can be considered an alternative to migration squashing, but obviously a last resort if you already have production data in the db. But in that case, one should apply model changes with care and consideration anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually delete all references to Report from your migrations
2. Delete reports table from DB
3. Run python manage.py makemigrations. It will create new migration for Report.
4. Push, deploy.